# Can not use components from imported module

Tags: module, angular13

I have a simple task I'm trying to accomplish. I've created a `SharedModule` with a component called `InputComponent`. I want to use this component in `SigninComponent` which is part of the `AuthModule`. I export the `InputComponent` from `SharedModule` and import the `SharedModule` into the `AuthModule`. However, when I use `<app-input>`, I get the following error:

```
src/app/auth/signin/signin.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'app-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { InputComponent } from './input/input.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    InputComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    InputComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css']
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label?:string;
  @Input() inputType?:string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { SignoutComponent } from './signout/signout.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SigninComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    SignoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**signin.component.html**

```
<h1>Sign In</h1>
<form>
    <app-input inputType="email" label="Email Address"></app-input>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something small and just can't figure it out.

**Extra note**
I have other components within the same `AuthModule` (`SignoutComponent` for example), that will throw the same error if I try to use `<app-signout>`

Comment: Solved! I needed to add the AuthModule to the AppModule due to eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here just incase someone runs into something similar.

Due to how I had routing setup, I was eagerly loading my Auth components. (not lazy loading) In order to get this to work, I needed to import my `AuthModule` to my `AppModule`.